# SQL Server: GROUP BY with multiple columns produces duplicate results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to include a 3rd column into my existing SQL Server query but I am getting duplicate result values.

Here is an example of the data contained in `tb_IssuedPermits`:

```
| EmployeeName | Current |
|--------------|---------|
| Person A     | 0       |
| Person A     | 0       |
| Person B     | 1       |
| Person C     | 0       |
| Person B     | 0       |
| Person A     | 1       |
```

This is my current query which produces duplicate values based on 1 or 0 bit values.

```sql
SELECT EmployeeName, COUNT(*) AS Count, [Current]
FROM tb_IssuedPermits
GROUP BY EmployeeName, [Current]
```

```
| EmployeeName | Count | Current |
|--------------|-------|---------|
| Person A     | 2     | 0       |
| Person B     | 1     | 0       |
| Person C     | 1     | 0       |
| Person A     | 1     | 1       |
| Person B     | 1     | 1       |
```

Any ideas on how I can amend my query to have the following expected result? I want one result row per `EmployeeName`. And `Current` shall be 1, if for the `EmployeeName` exists a row with `Current = 1`, else it shall be 0.

```
| EmployeeName | Count | Current |
|--------------|-------|---------|
| Person A     | 3     | 1       |
| Person B     | 2     | 1       |
| Person C     | 1     | 0       |
```

The result does not need to be in any specific order.

TIA

Comment: Which column defines the order of the rows (to get the `current` status)?

Comment: @Zhorov the column is called `Current`. I included an example of what data is contained within the table itself (only two columns)

Comment: @ayushlal, your `Person A` has both **true** and **false** for the `Current` column. Thats why when you group it using `Current` it creates duplicate - because there are both true and false. any rule on how the `Current` value is taken in the desired final result?

Comment: Rows in a table have no defined order. Just because you LIST them visually in a certain manner does not mean you can retrieve the "last" one - that requires a column or columns that can be used to determine "last".

Comment: is there any other column in the table like createDate column?

Comment: Thanks @BagusTesa, I understand that. I'd like for it to display `TRUE` if it actually contains a TRUE value in the Current column otherwise FALSE and the count should still remain distinct with no duplications

Comment: I think I poorly worded my question. Let me rephrase

Comment: @ayushlal, its better to be clear. we can assume stuff, but we cant be sure if our assumption is correct for your question - thats why we need to clarify :)

Comment: In your case `SELECT EmployeeName, Count(*) AS Count, MAX([Current]) AS [Current] ... `  is enough. But, as a more general approach, you need to number the rows (to get the latest row) and a windowed `SUM`.

Comment: Hi guys, I have edited my question with more detail

Comment: @yush: I've edited the request with an explanation on what you want. Sample data is nice, but there must always be a clear explanation in a request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `Current` column contains the string values `'FALSE'` and `'TRUE'` you can do this

```
SELECT EmployeeName, Count(*) AS Count, 
       MAX([Current]) AS Current
  FROM tb_IssuedPermits
 GROUP BY EmployeeName
```

It's a hack but it works: MAX will get the TRUE from each group if there is one.

If your `Current` column is a `BIT`, cast to `INT` and cast back, as [@ThorstenKettner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72068207/sql-server-group-by-with-multiple-columns-produces-duplicate-results#comment127340114_72068368) suggested.

```
SELECT EmployeeName,
       Count(*) AS Count, 
       CAST(MAX(CAST([Current] AS INT)) AS BIT) AS Current
  FROM tb_IssuedPermits
 GROUP BY EmployeeName
```

Alternatively, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT EmployeeName,
       Count(*) AS Count, 
       CAST(COUNT(NULLIF(Current, 0)) AS BIT) AS Current
  FROM tb_IssuedPermits
 GROUP BY EmployeeName
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the `Current` column contains BIT values instead. I have edited my question.

Comment: Then cast your bit to an integer: `MAX(CAST(current AS INT))`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
SELECT EmployeeName, Count(1) AS Count,SUM(CAST([Current]AS INT)) AS Current FROM tb_IssuedPermits GROUP BY EmployeeName
```